# How to logout from ASP.NET web application, if webapi token based authentication reaches it's expire time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

My web application is using web api which is token based authentication. Its expire time is set as one hour. How can I check it in my app and set the system to logout when reaches this expire time?

```
   var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

 {
"access_token": "GjNT5eNHOxwp1JRnEveHo_ensDBCoLkhZ5jBgN2hR_tYOU7_lRXtdKav12KUTXBHtuzc22i21j9oNve0h0lh1L8YcPfrzdzGExcCVKNvXqSv6HTGA1YOn99uwGFWj3o6SNLwz4_2ljA0QnX1QFkM4NJ9HtMxWKROOeqBr87ODZFWZh1Tc4wNv7PGVX8G6OMj12Q0mQ",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3599
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using HttpClient. So when reading the HttpResponseMessage, you can get the status code in the response and based on it, perform an action.
You can find all status codes in:
[HttpStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8)

For the outdated token, it'll return 401 Unauthorized which means the user has to login again to get a new token. So reading the status code 401 will determine the token status.